# Adding System.Data.SQLite reference in IronPython

Tags: ado.net, ironpython, system.data.sqlite

I'm trying to use clr.AddReference to add sqlite3 functionality to a simple IronPython program I'm writing; but everytime I try to reference System.Data.SQLite I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   IOError: System.IO.IOException: Could not add reference to assembly System.Data.SQLite
>      at Microsoft.Scripting.Actions.Calls.MethodCandidate.Caller.Call(Object[] args, Boolean&shouldOptimize)
>      at IronPython.Runtime.Types.BuiltinFunction.BuiltinFunctionCaller`2.Call1(CallSite site, CodeContext context, TFuncType func, T0 arg0)
>
>      at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
>
>      at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , CodeContext , Object , Object )
>
>      at IronPython.Compiler.Ast.CallExpression.Invoke1Instruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
>
>      at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
>
>      at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
>
>      at IronPython.Runtime.FunctionCode.Call(CodeContext context)
>
>      at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.QualifiedExec(CodeContext context, Object code, PythonDictionary globals, Object locals)
>
>      at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
>      at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

I've been testing out the imports and references in the interpreter mainly, and these are the lines I test:

> import sys
>   import clr
>   sys.path.append("C:/Program Files (x86)/SQLite.NET/bin")
>   clr.AddReference("System.Data.SQLite")

The error happens after the clr.AddReference line is entered. How would I add System.Data.SQLite properly?

Comment: I downloaded SQLite.NET, and your sample code works perfectly for me. Double check the path to SQLite is correct?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that you're trying to load the x86 (32-bit) System.Data.SQLite.dll in a x64 (64-bit) process, or vice versa. System.Data.SQLite.dll contains the native sqlite3 library, which must be compiled for x86 or x64, so there is a version of System.Data.SQLite.dll for each CPU.

If you're using the console, ipy.exe is always 32-bit (even on 64-bit platforms) while ipy64.exe is AnyCPU, so it matches the current platform. If you're hosting IronPython, and the host app is AnyCPU, you need to load the right copy of System.Data.SQLite.dll for the machine you're running on (or just force the host app x86).